# Best way to remove my question from unanswered section?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

[Determine conditions for $a,b>0$ such that $f(x)=\sum b^n\sin(a^nx)$ be continuous but nowhere differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245285/determine-conditions-for-a-b0-such-that-fx-sum-bn-sinanx-be-continuo)

was answered with a paper, but if you see the unanswered questions list is still there. Since answer is a comment.

Comment: [What should one do when one's question has been answered in the comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ty, but, why you answered with a comment? that's ironic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either comment to Gerry Myerson, asking him to post the information in his comment as an answer, or post an answer with that information yourself (it is common, when doing the latter, to make the answer CW, since it is not your answer *per se*).

Comment: ty, now I replied him

Comment: And I complied.

Comment: The option to make the answer CW does not offend anyone, true? Or is it always better to ask first the person that answered (in the comments) to post the answer?